# How to handle Ajax-generated form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So I use this Javascript to handle forms:

```
$(':submit:not(.form-default-submit)').click(function(event) {
    //Disable normal form submission, handle using ajax
});
```

It works correctly in most cases. So any submit element with the class `form-default-submit` is ignored, and all others are handled in this Javascript.

But I've just noticed that this doesn't work for Ajax-generated content. Which I'm guessing is because this code is run on page load, before the Ajax content is loaded.

I see people using:

```
$(document).on("click", selector, function(e){
```

As a fix for this. But in my case, I don't just apply it to the element directly. I have that condition to allow exceptions for elements with the class `form-default-submit`.

Is the only way to do this with the new Ajax-supported method to have an if statement within the function checking if the element has a particular class? Or can I do this within the selector itself? This is a bit above my current ability, so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on( "click",":submit:not(.form-default-submit)", function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `submit` event directly to the form and `return false`. This will also catch a form sent by using the `enter` key.

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(event){

    // Send form data by AJAX
    $.post(...);

    // Prevent form to be sent the regular way
    return false;

});
```